# Problems with vector return/addition algorithm

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<int> add_vectors(const vector<int> &first, const vector<int> &second){
    vector<int> result;
    int length = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    int firsts_size = first.size();
    int seconds_size = second.size();

    if (firsts_size >= seconds_size){
        int length = firsts_size;
    }
    else{
        int length = seconds_size;
    }

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        int digit_sum = first[i] + second[i] + carry;
        if (digit_sum > 9){
            carry = ((digit_sum / 10) % 10);
        }
        result.push_back(digit_sum);
    }
    return result;
}
```

So hey guys, you have all helped me out a couple of times and I am hoping that you can do the same thing again for me.  So the purpose of this function in a C++ program is to take two vectors with digits, taken from large numbers, and to add them together and create a vector in the end with the sum to return from the function.  However, I am having an issue with this, and I can't tell if it is a problem with the way I have done the actual addition or if some way I am printing them out in my main.

I have created another function to take a vector comprised of digits and turn it into a string to print back out as output, and I know this function works because it works a lot throughout my program.  So I am convinced that something is going on with this function and causing me not to be able to print.  However, Visual Studio does not throw any errors from it or anything, simply that where the output is supposed to be is left blank, which has left me stumped.  Any help is greatly appreciated!! Just remember one thing, since this is the first program from my class I can't use anything too advanced to solve this issue.  Thanks for the Help

Comment: The algorithm is not clear. For the number 12345 , the vector first[0] is 1 or 5? It should be much better to have it 5 (associate the index of the digit in the vector with the respective power of 10). Moreover, the position length of you vectors will go to the position 0 of your result... are you reverting the ordering ot the original vectors in the result vector on purpose?

Comment: See the purpose was for me to do something like this: vector1 = 1234
vector2 = 5678, then adding them together, but the reason I am starting at 4 instead of 1 is to start at the ones digit and at the tens digit add the carry if there is one.  Then I have a function to reverse the number at the end

Comment: If you have this function to reverse the number, do it before to go to the function I post below, and then do it again after the function. You will have the vectors in the order that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you have the position i of the vector associated with the (i-1)-th power of 10.

EDITED: now it works also with different size vectors

```
vector<int> add_vectors(const vector<int> &first, const vector<int> &second){
vector<int> result;
int length = 0;
int carry = 0;
int firsts_size = first.size();
int seconds_size = second.size();
int digit_sum = 0;

if (firsts_size >= seconds_size){
    length = firsts_size; // int here is not necessary
}
else{
    length = seconds_size; // int here is not necessary
}

for (int i = 0, i<lenght; i++){
    if (i>=lenght){
        if (i>=firsts_size){
            digit_sum = second[i] + carry;
        }
        else{ 
            digit_sum = first[i] + carry;
        }
    }
    else{ 
        digit_sum = first[i] + second[i] + carry;
    }
    if (digit_sum > 9){
        carry = 1; // carry will be no mor than 1 adding two numbers
        digit_sum = digit_sum - 10;
    }
    else{
    carry = 0; 
    }
    result.push_back(digit_sum);
}
if (carry > 0){
    result.push_back(carry);
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: Great, this works like a charm and I should have seen this all along.  However what about the case where the numbers aren't the same length???

Comment: You would get a vector subscript out of range error if you were adding say 100 and 1000.  Also to a certain extent the algorithm has a flaw, because say you added 34567 and 34567 you get an extra digit in the ten thousandths place.

Comment: In the algorithm above, for the position 0 of the vector I have the one digit, for the position 1 I have the ten digits, ...

Comment: does the revised code has an error because when you get to the if(digit_sum > 9) line, digit_sum is undefined. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It has been defined in the if(i>=length)

Comment: Visual Studio continues to throw a digit_sum is undefined right there at that line, and I'm not sure as to why?

Comment: The vector digit_sum is defined at the begining. A value is also assigned before this if(digit_sum >9). I am not able to compile it now because I dont have a compiler in this computer, sorry.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help!! You have been tremendous!!  One last "pick your brain" question.  Now, I can add 9+1 and get 10, but why would I get another vector subscript out of range if i tried adding, say 99 + 1???